# NextJS custom hook doesn't react to state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a custom hook called `usePosts`. As you can see i pass variables `userId, status` for arguments.

Status is session status and if session is loading don't fetch posts till session is loaded.

But only empty object `{}` returns from hook, any idea why?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
    
    const usePosts = async (userId, status) => {
        const [posts, setPosts] = useState()
    
        const fetchPosts = async (u, cb) => {
            const pixels = await fetch(
                `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/posts/findbycreator`,
                {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                  body: JSON.stringify({ id: u }),
                }
              ).then((r) => r.json())
        
              return cb(pixels.posts)
        }
    
        useEffect(() => {
            if(status !== 'loading'){
                fetchPosts(userId, (p) => {
                    setPosts(p)
                    console.log(posts)
                })
            }
        }, [status])
        
    
        return posts
    }
    
    export default usePosts
```

Comment: If you log `pixels` to the console, what's the output?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons why this is happening, however, I could notice some caveats that might add up to this.

In your `fetchPosts` you are wrongly using `await` and `then`. `await` is not supposed to be used in complement with `then`, instead you should use either of them.
Update the code to this:

```
const fetchPosts = async (u, cb) => {
            const pixels = await fetch(
                `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/posts/findbycreator`,
                {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                  body: JSON.stringify({ id: u }),
                }
              )
            const pixelsInJson = await pixels.json()

        
            cb(pixelsInJson.posts) //No need to return the value if it is consumed directly.
        }
```

Or

```
const fetchPosts = (u, cb) => {
            fetch(
                `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/posts/findbycreator`,
                {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                  body: JSON.stringify({ id: u }),
                }
              ).then((r) => r.json())
              .then(pixels => cb(pixels.posts)) 
       
        }
```

The state type of `posts` is not defined during the state declaration. Although this might not throw errors upfront if used with JavaScript, it is always prone to show irregular behavior during runtime.
Define the type of `posts` in `useState`.

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]) //Assuming posts is an array of posts, but if it something else, feel free to update it as required.
```

Your `useEffect` hook is triggered whenever the `status` changes and `status` is not `loading`, meaning the `if` block is executed even when `status` is `undefined` or any falsy values. So you'd want to make sure you are handling such edge cases.

The above steps do not guarantee a fix. But it might help you figure out the cause of the error better. Maybe if could throw more context on how/where this custom hook is being invoked, it'll be easier to identify the problem.